# Google Cloud Console Logs Explorer. How to find top ip address that requested my website?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

In Google Cloud, how can I know the IP addresses that requested my website the most? I mean list like this

```
12.12.12.12 - 2189 requests
13.14.15.12 - 1987 requests
...
```

Comment: Google Cloud Logging does not calculate that information for you. Cloud Logging provides storage for raw log data. Use a third-party product that takes raw log files and display data in your designed format. Otherwise, review the format of the data stored in Cloud Logging. Then write a program that reads that data and tabulates your desired information.

Comment: @JohnHanley thx. I somehow managed to view it at glance and dig some info I needed. Post as answer and I make it answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In Google Cloud, how can I know the IP addresses that requested my
> website the most?

Google Cloud Logging does not calculate that information for you. Cloud Logging provides storage for raw log data. Use a third-party product that takes raw log files and display data in your designed format.

Otherwise, review the format of the data stored in Cloud Logging. Then write a program that reads that data and tabulates your desired information.